# Local ESM module dependencies not resolving

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I am attempting to import a local ESM package into a node 16 application. The application is unable to resolve the local package dependencies outputting the following error.

```
    Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@prismicio/client' imported from /Users/***/Workspace/wisdom-store/lib/prismic-utils/index.mjs
    at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:664:9)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:705:18)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:819:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:89:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:242:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:73:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:72:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

The consuming node application is declaring the local package in the devDependencies using the file option.

```
{
  "name": "node-application",
  "devDependencies" : {
      "prismic-utils": "file:../lib/prismic-utils"
  }
}
```

The local package (pismic-utils) defines @prismicio/client as a dependency.

```
{   
  "name": "prismic-utils",   
  "version": "0.0.0",  
  "private": true,  
  "main": "index.mjs",   
  "dependencies": {
    "@prismicio/helpers": "^2.3.9",
    "@prismicio/client": "^6.7.3"
  },   
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.35.0",
     "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
     "msw": "^1.1.0",
     "node-fetch": "^3.3.0",
     "vitest": "^0.28.5"
  } 
}
```

I am at a complete loss as to why the consuming node application is having trouble resolving the @prismicio/client and @prismicio/helpers inherited dependencies. If I populate the node_modules folder inside the local package the node application resolves the dependencies. The local prismic-utils package dependencies are being installed to the consuming application node_modules folder.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because using `file:` in a dependency's version results in a symbolic link. It acts like `npm link` ([see `npm link` docs here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-link)).

npm treats linked packages differently than those installed from a registry like npmjs.com. npm assumes the linked package has its own dependencies installed, so it does not install them.

There are a few ways to resolve your issue:

1. **Best Option**: Use [npm workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/workspaces) to automatically handle linked dependency installation.

   Update your `package.json` file to include a `workspaces` property:

   ```json
   // package.json

   {
     "workspaces": [
       "./relative/path/to/prismic-utils",
       "./relative/path/to/app"
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Install `file:` dependencies like registry dependencies using [npm's `--install-links` option](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-link#install-links).

   ```bash
   # In the Node.js app:
   npm install --install-links
   ```

   Changes to `prismic-utils` **will not** be reflected in the app until it is re-installed, just like non-`file:` dependencies.

   **Note**: Dependencies' `devDependencies` are not installed using this method. You will need to move `node-fetch` from `devDependencies` into `dependencies`.
3. Install dependencies in `prismic-utils` before starting your app. Once they are installed, `prismic-utils` will have access to its own dependencies via its `node_modules` directory.

Because you are using Node.js 16, which includes npm >=7 and support for workspaces, Option 1 is the best choice.

Comment: Thank you Angelo you are spot on with the workspaces.  Unfortunately I am having trouble with node workspaces and pinning other project dependencies via overrides.   The --install-links option is what I was looking for.  Thanks for the tips. node-fetch is a dev dependency as fetch is injected via the consuming applications.